# Ruby/Rails - How to write this syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I'm using Doorkeeper and if I modify `current_user` in any way, like put it in a conditional statement using unless or if, Doorkeeper won't pick it up.  Is there a simple way I can keep `current_user ||` and fit the next two lines containing the session store and redirect to work in one line to the right of the double pipe?

```
resource_owner_authenticator do

  current_user ||

  session[:after_login_redirect_to] = request.fullpath
  redirect_to('/connect')   

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly make an expression out of multiple lines of code, simply wrap them in brackets.

```
current_user || (session[:after_login_redirect_to] = request.fullpath; redirect_to('/connect'))
```

Comment: Word of warning: when you pack that much logic into a line you are probably doing something wrong. One line methods are great, but not at the cost of complexity, one line methods are to **reduce** complexity, reading that huge one liner is harder that reading a well done multi-liner.

Answer (score 6):

No need to make it a one liner - use a begin block:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  current_user || begin
    session[:after_login_redirect_to] = request.fullpath
    redirect_to('/connect')   
  end
end
```